# Sinhala language unicode characters are swapped or jumbled in sap crystal reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm new to crystal reports.I have stored data in the Sinhala language as Unicode format into the access database, when it displaying in Crystal Report characters are swapped. In My development Machine, It work properly but in my client machine, the sinhala unicode characters are swapped. any solution? I tried with different Sinhalese fonts, but still, have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

what is the crystal report version you are using. only crystal report versions above 8 supports unicord